# Why does Path/File discard trailing file separator?

Tags: java

Using the following code:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;

    class Target {
    String name;

    public Target() {
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    }


    public class Test {


    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Target target = new Target();
    target.setName("A");

    String tmpDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "tmp_" + target.getName() + File.separator;
            System.out.println("Tmp dir:  " + tmpDir);
            Path atfTmpPath= Paths.get(tmpDir);
            File filePath = atfTmpPath.toFile();

            System.out.println("Tmp path: " + atfTmpPath.toAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("Tmp file path: " + filePath.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    }
```

~

This produces the following output:

```
Tmp dir:  /home/john/tmp/tmp_A/
Tmp path: /home/john/tmp/tmp_A
Tmp file path: /home/john/tmp/tmp_A
```

Why is the trailing file separator removed? If I want to use the path later and copy files into it:

```
Files.copy(src, atfTmpPath);
```

The copy fails (FileAlreadyExistsException)  (I think!) because it thinks that the target is a file instead of a directory because it is missing the trailing file separator. I can't find any way to make Path into a directory path.

Comment: Note that with `copy()` the second parameter is the path to the target *file*, you can't use a directory as a target.

Comment: So Files.copy is the equivalent of `cp test1.log test2.log`, but cannot do `cp test1.log test2/`, if `test2` is a directory?? Surely not...

Comment: It surely can't...

Comment: Wow! The [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) say:                                                                            _This class consists exclusively of static methods that operate on files, directories, or other types of files._ Surely copying a file into a directory would be a reasonable assumption for `Files.copy` based on that blurb. I guess not.

Comment: It appears that you have to do the equivalent of : cp test1.log test2/test1.log. The target file name is not inferred from the copy operation. It has to be specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The copy fails (FileAlreadyExistsException) (I think!) because it thinks that the target is a file instead of a directory

Correct.

> because it is missing the trailing file separator.

No. Because the API is specified to take a file as the target. There is nothing in the Javadoc about allowing the target to be a directory.

> I can't find any way to make Path into a directory path.

It wouldn't matter if you did: the operation would still fail.

Comment: This worked for me: `Files.copy(src, dest.resolve(src.getFileName()), REPLACE_EXISTING);`